# How to create a UINavigationController with a UITableViewController as root, all within Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

1) In my app delegate I create the root view controller which is a navigation controller:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootNavigationController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

2) "RootNavigationController.xib" creates a `UINavigationController`. It also defines a root view controller, which is a `CatsViewController : UITableViewController`. There is a CatsViewController file and a "CatsViewController.xib" with a UITableViewController root object. Like you can see in this screenshot I set the NIB Name accordingly:

[image]

The problem is, Xcode doesn't let me select CatsViewController from the dropdown even if there is a CatsViewController.xib file. I want the XIB for my UINavigationController to create an instance of CatsViewController as it's root, and I want to configure this root controller through a separate nib file.

Xcode warns:

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the AppDelegate trying to initialize the window and not just returning YES.

also in your code change the RootNavigationController, like:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootNavigationController" bundle:nil];
```

change it to

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CatsViewController" bundle:nil];
```